# Prerequisites and introduction to string theory

Tags: string-theory, soft-question, resource-recommendations

Can someone please give me the prerequisites and mathematics required for string theory? Are there some good references to study it, both online and in a book? Please consider I am a newbie in string theory, and only about up to the level explained in Hawking's Brief History of Time and Penrose's Road to Reality. I would prefer something which does not omit rigor, but builds it up.Also, are there good online lectures on this?

(I have covered most of GR, but I am not really comfortable with advanced Quantum mechanics. I have studied QM only from Griffith's book, and a few McGraw hill lecture notes.)